# DoJo addOnLoad is not working for few stores

Tags: dojo, wcs, dojo-1.8

I have migrated one store from Elite to Aurora and dojo addOnLoad is working fine for it. While I migrated other stores, it is not working for any of the stores with same code base.

Later I found out that i need to comment `"dojo/domReady!",` to make `dojo.addOnLoad` work on these stores.

`dojo.addOnLoad` was used in < 1.7 DOJO version and same behavior is achieved by `"dojo/domReady!",` in 1.7+. So can't we use both together at different placed if we are using DOJO 18.

Let me know if more details are required.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem is that if you use the dojo/domReady! that who require function will not be kicked off till after the dom is ready.  So whatever you have inside the require would be redundant

Comment: Thanks tik27.. You mean to say if I am using dojo/domReady!, I can remove the dojo.addOnLoad function and code inside written in this function will execute once dom is ready/all dojo related files are loaded on browser. Correct me If I am wrong.